# Extracting embedded images from a PDF results in tiny stripes

Tags: command-line, pdf, gimp, png

I have an important pdf where I need to extract the source image, as lossless as possible (e.g. using png)
For some reason, it seems that the source image is made out of 226 image stripes, and when I extract these e.g. with

```
pdfimages -png name.pdf out-
```

I get the 227 tiny stripes. That is not what I want. Is there a way to get one single image instead? Using *pdfimages -list* tells me the info about the stripes, and using e.g. the above *pdfimages -png name.pdf out-* gives me the 227 single images. One image is e.g. 1604 px width and 5 px height. So far as I checked them, all images seem to be 5 px height, and with 227 single images, I should get one single image of 1604 x 1135 px instead.

**Update**
I forgot to add what Ryan J. Yoder wrote below was also my own thought on the issue, meaning that the pdf was indeed created by splitting the original image into 227 stripes.

And in conclusion, if that is so (*pdfimages -list* says it is so) is there a way to automatically create one single image out of the stripes e.g. by using graphicsmagick.

Comment: It's possible the images are actually embedded as multiple "stripes".

Comment: @RyanJ.Yoder This is what I presume, but why was it made like so, and could it be automatically be made into one image? It would take too long to put all 227 stripes together e.g. in mtpaint or GIMP manually. Could this be automated e.g. with graphicsmagick?

Comment: You could use imagemagick's [append operation](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append).

Comment: @danzel seems "-append" is able to do the trick. :) I look into it, but now RL calls for me.

Comment: There are scripts for gimp to tile/untile an image. The strips are all the same size and can be sorted by name in the position order, then this should be simple job. See `ofn-tiles` and `ofn-layer-tiles` [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)

Comment: Thanks *@dessert* and *xenoid* for these heads up. RL keeps me too busy so it may take some days till I can check out but me thinks both would be good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript can be used to get images of the pages as they appear in a viewer, e.g. for `.png` images with 300 dpi named `out_001.png`, `out_002.png`, … from `in.pdf`:

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=out_%03d.png in.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks @dessert sounds very god, too busy the next week or 2 weeks, but I will check it out, your solutions sounds like the best so far.

Comment: @Rava Did you find a chance to try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageMagick to 'convert' the PDF to a png using the command line:

`convert -density 300 page.pdf page.png`

or whatever density (DPI) you'd like.